# Possible to set "Addresses to send from" in OWA (Exchange Online) using EXO V3 PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, exo

I want to script updating the list of choices for users in OWA when they select a "From" address:

[image: screenshot of picklist when expanding the Send From field in OWA]

The way to do this manually is to open Outlook online, go to Settings [Gear Icon] -> Compose and reply ->

[image]

I assume there is a way to set this in PowerShell too (or was?) but the current [EXO V3 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps#powershell-v3-module) does not offer any obvious paths. ([Plenty of information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=SendAs) on how to enable Send As and delegate permissions, but not relevant to this question)

This question was asked in a different forum [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/setting-owa-address-to-send-from-preferences-via/3ece2555-9b75-4505-a91c-71b4cb7e5fdf), but the Microsoft rep who answered the question proposed a command that seems to be either outdated or incorrect. The proposed solution there was:

```
Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration -Identity <UserPrincipalName> -SendAsPermissions @{Add="<EmailAddress1>","<EmailAddress2>"}
```

However this throws an error when I run it in my environment, and also does not appear to conform to the [current documented available commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxmessageconfiguration?view=exchange-ps#parameters) in the Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration cmdlet.

To summarize: I don't need to add additional aliases / proxyAddresses, they're already there and I can confirm that with

```
Get-ExoMailbox -Identity foo.bar | Select -ExpandProperty emailaddresses
```

I want to automate the process of adding choices to the from field for already existing addresses so that the users do not have to manually add their aliases.